# jGit Push not always visible in GitHub Activity page

Tags: git, github, github-actions, jgit

I use jGit to manage repositories, and I have a question related to push().

The issue: not all pushes are visible in the GitHub activity page.
In the workflow below, Ben is pushing a change to GitHub without doing a pull before.
His changes won't be visible in the GitHub activity pane.

| Rob | Ben |
| --- | --- |
| Modifies file sakila.txt adding a 'Rob' line |  |
| Stages the file sakila.txt |  |
| commits the changes **CRob** |  |
| push to origin |  |
| **CRob** is visible in GitHub activity |  |
|  | Modifies sakila.txt adding a 'Ben' line |
|  | Stages the file sakila.txt |
|  | commits the changes **CBen** |
|  | Pushes to origin **CBen** |
|  | **CBen** is not visible in GitHub activity |

**Staging**

git.add().addFilepattern('sakila.txt').call();

**Commiting I do a fetch first**

git.fetch().setRemote("origin").call();

git.commit().setMessage(...).setAuthor(...).call();

**Push**

git.push().setRemote("origin").call();

Comment: If Rob and Ben are pushing to the same branch, Ben's request is rejected as it would override Rob's changes. Ben would need to fetch and rebase first or force-push (usually not advisable with shared repositories). JGit's push command returns a data structure that describes the outcome of the operation so that your software can act accordingly.

Comment: I've overlooked that Ben did not commit the changes. Thus Ben tries to push `origin/branch~1` (assuming Rob and Ben started at the same commit). However, the end result should be the same: a fast-forward push is not possible and the return value of `call()` will indicate that.

Comment: I did debug on push.call() result and there was no error. Also I couldn't find any method to set fast-forward on push. Only on pull I found it.

Comment: You say it's not visible in the activity page. Is the git repo in the desired state? Because if it's "just" the activity page that's missing things then it's a different kind of issue than if the git repo doesn't represent the desired state.

Comment: Not sure what 'no error' means. AFAIK rejecting a remote update isn't considered an error in JGit/Git. It might be worth amending the question with the push result, in particular `getRemoteUpdates()`.